# HTML 5 Not Acceptable Response (406) Error

Tags: html

Bizarre issue, I've written a small html5 website, when I add a line of text to a 
"p" tag, the server returns:

**Not Acceptable
An appropriate representation of the requested resource /emp.html could not be found on this server.**

http://lbargers.0fees.net/emp.html

Below is the chunk of html that should be displayed. If I change the text "RemoteView", to "Remote View", the page loads correctly with no errors, however it fails with Not Acceptable Response (406) Error if I keep it "RemoteView".

"The analyst will note any infrastructure changes and use ARCGIS data, **RemoteView**, Imagery Analysis, data conversion, and other sources of newer vintage imagery to compare information gleaned through data imagery to the existing data."

page markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>L.C. Wright, Inc. - Staff</title>
<meta name="description" content="website description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<!-- modernizr enables HTML5 elements and feature detects -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-2.6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/smalllogo.png" />
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div id="menu_container">
                <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="corporategoals.html">Corporate Goals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="recentactivities.html">Recent Activities</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="mda.html">MDA</a></li>
                            <li><a href="jnic.html">JNIC</a></li>
                            <li><a href="defenseia.html">DIA</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="emp.html">Employment Opportunities</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="gsaschedule.html">GSA Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="site_content">
        <div id="sidebar_container">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <h3>Latest News</h3>
                <h4>New Website Launched</h4>
                <h5>September 1st, 2013</h5>
                <span>
                    2013 sees the redesign of our website. Take a look around and let us know what you think.<br />
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <h3>Documents</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="documents/LCW%20infograph%20-%20081913.pptx">Infograph</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>L.C. Wright, Inc. Staff</h1>
             <p>L.C. Wright, Inc. is always looking for highly qualified individuals in the areas of Software Engineering, Modeling and Simulation, Information Technology, Test Engineers and Mathematics.</p>
            <p>Locations include: National Capital Region (NCR), Colorado Springs, CO, and Huntsville, AL.</p>
            <address>
                E-mail resumes to: <a href="mailto:lcwrightjobs@gmail.com">L.C. Wright Jobs</a>
            </address>

            <p><b>Current Openings:</b></p>
            <p>Positions require U.S. citizenship and the ability to obtain a security clearance. </p>
            <p><b>AVAILABLE POSITIONS</b></p>

            <h3>Electrical Engineer - National Capital Region (NCR)</h3>
            <p>Experienced engineer specializing in transmission and distribution feeder studies. Develop models representing electrical infrastructures with understanding of model's capabilities and has the capacity to present findings in a clear and precise format to Government customers. The engineer will update PowerWorld and other models for specific geographical areas as requested by the customer, utilizing various scenarios and future projections. Will run powerflow, voltage stability, and transient stability simulations to determine power system performance under a range of possible load, generation and topology conditions. This is a highly visible position and program, and candidates should be prepared to take initiative and be proactive, anticipating custoemr needs and addressing issues.</p>
            <p><b>Basic Qualifications:</b> Familiar with software modeling applications such as Powerworld. BS degree or higher in Electrical Engineering. At least 5 years in data analysis, 5 years experience in transmission and distribution studies.</p>
            <p><b>Preferred Qualifications:</b> At least 10 years in data analysis, PowerWorld expeirence, Master's degree in Electrical Engineering, EIT and PE preferred. </p>
            <p><b>Clearance:</b> TS/SCI or ability to obtain. Position contingent on contract award.</p>

            <h3>Intelligence Analyst - NCR </h3>
            <p>The analyst works with drawings, shapefiles, and various classified databases to obtain data for a specified geographical area. The analyst will note any infrastructure changes and use ARCGIS data, Remote View, Imagery Analysis, data conversion, and other sources of newer vintage imagery to compare information gleaned through data imagery to the existing data. This data is then analyzed for correctness and relevancy to the particular geographic area that requires updating. </p>
            <p><b>Basic Qualifications:</b> Data analysis experience, Shapefile development, ARCGIS experience, Remote View, Imagery Analysis, data conversion, background in intelligence and databases.</p>
            <p><b>Preferred Qualifications:</b> BS degree or higher, 10+ years of experience in data analysis.</p>
            <p><b>Clearance:</b> TS/SCI or ability to obtain. Position contingent on contract award.</p>

            <h3>2361 - Messaging Services Team Lead - Colorado Springs, CO</h3>
            <p>A senior-level lead engineer responsible for leading MDA Exhchange team in supporting installation, maintenance, testing, troubleshooting, and support of hardwaree, software, and associated tools in a Microsoft Windows Active Directory Exchange environment. Masters degree in an IT-related discipline and at least 20 years of experience. At least 10 years relevant w ork experience with Messaging systems. Extensive experience with Microsoft Exchange 2007/2010, Blackberry Enterprise Server, Barrracuda SPAM firewalls, messaging technologies and their interaction with Windows Active Directory. Experience with Windows PowerShell and other administrative scripting platforms. Essential qualifications for a successful candidate include excellent leadership ability, a strong commitment to a team environment, the ability to quickly adapt to new situations, and good communication skills. Must have a DoD Secret clerance or ability to obtain. CompTIA Security+ certification required to satisfy DoD 8570 requirements oro the ability to obtain within 60 days of hire.</p>
            <p>L.C. Wright, Inc. is always looking for highly qualified individuals in the areas of Software Engineering, Modeling and Simulation, Test Engineers and Mathematics.</p>

            <address>
                E-mail resumes to: <a href="mailto:lcwrightjobs@gmail.com">L.C. Wright Jobs</a>
            </address>


        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <span>Copyright &copy; 2013 L.C. Wright, Inc.</span>
    </footer>
</div>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<!-- javascript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing-sooper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sooperfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.sf-menu').sooperfish();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I was able to narrow this down to the single term that is causing the issue, "RemoteView". Not exactly sure why but it is the cause of this problem. I changed the term to "Remote View", and it's loading correctly now. Does this mean that the server blocks certain phrases?

Comment: Some technical detail would help: What web server? What technology is the site using (static HTML, PHP, .Net etc.)? Also, posting the actual page code/markup would help.

Comment: This is static HTML5 on fees0.com, which is LAMP based. for now I'm only rendering html pages, without any php calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the term to "Remote View" from "RemoteView" solved my issue.